# $(\mathbb{E}\xi\eta)^m\leq (\mathbb{E}\xi)^{m-1}\mathbb{E}\xi\eta^m$

Tags: probability-theory

For $\xi,\eta$ positive random variables and $m>1$. Prove
$$(\mathbb{E}\xi\eta)^m\leq (\mathbb{E}\xi)^{m-1}\mathbb{E}\xi\eta^m$$
when the right side are assumed finite.

I have \begin{align*} (\mathbb{E}\xi\eta)^m&\leq \mathbb{E}\xi^{m}\mathbb{E}\eta^m\\ &=\mathbb{E}\xi^{m-1}\mathbb{E}\xi\mathbb{E}\eta^m\\ &=\mathbb{E}\xi^{m-1}\mathbb{E}\xi\eta^m \end{align*}

However, I can't figure out how to get the $m-1$ to the outside. Thanks!

Comment: You say that you have $(\mathbb{E}\xi\eta)^m\leq \mathbb{E}\xi^{m}\mathbb{E}\eta^m=\mathbb{E}\xi^{m-1}\mathbb{E}\xi\mathbb{E}\eta^m=\mathbb{E}\xi^{m-1}\mathbb{E}\xi\eta^m$. Actually, $(\mathbb{E}\xi\eta)^m\leq \mathbb{E}\xi^{m}\mathbb{E}\eta^m$ is true but $\mathbb{E}\xi^{m}\mathbb{E}\eta^m=\mathbb{E}\xi^{m-1}\mathbb{E}\xi{}{}{}\mathbb{E}\eta^m$  and $\mathbb{E}\xi^{m-1}\mathbb{E}\xi\mathbb{E}\eta^m=\mathbb{E}\xi^{m-1}{}{}{}{}{}{}\mathbb{E}\xi\eta^m$ are almost never true.

Answer (score 3):

$m$ and $\frac{m}{m-1}$ are conjugate exponents, hence Holder's inequality applied to $\xi^{\frac{m-1}{m}}$ and $\xi^{\frac{1}{m}}\eta$ yields
$$ \mathbb{E}(\xi\eta)\leq \mathbb{E}(\xi)^{\frac{m-1}{m}}\mathbb{E}(\xi\eta^m)^{\frac{1}{m}}$$

Now raise both sides to the $m$th power.